# Infinite summation involving exponents

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, summation

How can we solve the following?:

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}  \sum_{r=1}^N \frac{2^r}{(1+5^{2^r})} $$

The answer according to Wolfram Alpha is $\frac{1}{12}$, but I have no idea how it can be calculated on paper without summing it infinitely (which apparently is what Wolfram Alpha does).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{2^r}{5^{2^r}-1}-\dfrac{2^r}{5^{2^r}+1}=\dfrac{2^{r+1}}{5^{2^{r+1}}-1}$$

Use [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)