# Finding lim as $n \to \infty$ for $\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{2^r}{5^{2^r}+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

We need to find $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^n \frac{2^r}{5^{2^r}+1}$$

I tried finding a closed form for the sum and then plugging in the limit but I couldn't figure out any sort of telescoping or breakdown for this sum so my thoughts turned to the limit itself.

I thought that there was a possibility of converting it into an integral but that didn't work either. There is perhaps a possibility of using the Sandwich theorem but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621877/infinite-summation-involving-exponents

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638344/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-prod-k-0n-left1-frac2452k45-2k